# Unable to find the number of radio buttons in a section when there are two or more radio button sections are present

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Am currently learning Selenium on my own . i am trying to automate the below demo website https://itera-qa.azurewebsites.net/home/automation.
There is a section of radio button to select gender. i was trying to find the number of elements under that particular section . Page has another section of radio button too
If u notice the label gender it is not directly associated to the parent above ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMUSv.jpg)

Please help me to find the xpath so that i can find the number of  radio buttons in the particular section rather than that of the whole page . i spent lot of time in tweaking this

Answer (score 0):

Well, to select the Female radio button you should click on the `label` element above it. The Xpath for that `label` element is

```
//label[.//input[@id='female']]
```

or

```
//input[@id='female']/..
```

(Both are correct).
Similarly, to select Male radio button you can use

```
//label[.//input[@id='male']]
```

or

```
//input[@id='male']/..
```

Comment: No my question is not to select the radio button . I want to find the number of radio buttons under the particular label . the above page has two radio button sections.List<WebElement> radio=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@type='radio']"));
  System.out.println(radio.size());
  for (int i=0;i<radio.size();i++)
  {
   System.out.println("Step to check radio button selected or not "+radio.get(i).getAttribute("selected"));
} if i put the above code all the radio buttons in the page for example 8 radio buttons is the output .

Comment: Under what label?

Comment: but i need to find the number of radio buttons  in the particular section alone . For that i need to find the xpath pertainign to the radio button section and number of radio buttons in the particular section alone . Kindly help

Comment: What section? under what label?

Comment: i have added a screenshot above. Kindly check

Comment: <label for="gender">Gender</label>

Comment: Under the Gender section? is it so difficult to say it directly and shortly?

Comment: Those 3 radio buttons are NOT below the gender label element

Comment: Am trying to be as clear as possible . There are three radio buttons in the section under the header checkbox and radio button practice section . i want to find the number of radio buttons in the particular section alone . if i write the above piece of code mentioned in the above comment section all the radio buttons in the page .is displayed in the output . So i thought i can further narrow down by parent child relationship xpath but am unable to do it .

Comment: Again. These radio buttons elements are NOT below that label element. You don't understand the actual HTML structure of that page.

Comment: i understand that very well.. how to find the number of radio buttons in a particular section alone when it comes to this page

Comment: May i ask whats the restriction here .

Answer (score 0):

Try below `xpath` to count the radio button under `Gender` section.

```
//div[contains(@class,'body-content')]/div[3]//input[@type='radio']
```

Below code is in python, but you should be able to understand what I am doing

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://itera-qa.azurewebsites.net/home/automation")
time.sleep(5)
radio = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'body-content')]/div[3]//input[@type='radio']")
print(len(radio))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Split the `xpath` to understand.

```
//div[contains(@class,'body-content')]- points the entire page, 
//div[contains(@class,'body-content')]/div - gives all 6 parts of the form.
//div[contains(@class,'body-content')]/div[3]` points to the 3rd `div` where the required radio buttons exists and 
//div[contains(@class,'body-content')]/div[3]//input[@type='radio']` points to `input` tags with `type` `radio` only. Replace `radio` with `checkbox` to point only on the checkboxes
Suppose you want radio buttons of `Years of experience in test automation` below is the xpath. Its the 5th `div` tag in the entire page.
//div[contains(@class,'body-content')]/div[5]//input[@type='radio']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding and answering my question . the xpath worked . Can you please tell me how u figured out so that i will try the same for other radio button section in the same page . from the xpath u typed i understand this is not parent child or ancesstor relationship .